# Fast BERT Camembert, arguments located on different GPUs error

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, gpu, text-classification

I'm trying to implement Fast-Bert with 'camembert-base' model type.
I can easily create my databunch with BertLMDatabunch.From raw_corpus
then I create the learner.
I'm on a cloud env, with 3 GPUs, on ubuntu env, with 32 cores and RAM 130Mo.
When I'm trying to fit the model I always have this error message after this information

```
databunch_lm = BertLMDataBunch.from_raw_corpus(
                data_dir=DATA_PATH,
                text_list=all_texts,
                tokenizer='camembert-base',
                batch_size_per_gpu=16,
                max_seq_length=512,
                multi_gpu=True,
                model_type='camembert-base',
                logger=logger)
lm_learner = BertLMLearner.from_pretrained_model(
                        dataBunch=databunch_lm,
                        pretrained_path='camembert-base',
                        output_dir=MODEL_PATH,
                        metrics=[],
                        device=device_cuda,
                        logger=logger,
                        multi_gpu=True,
                        logging_steps=50,
                        fp16_opt_level="O2")

lm_learner.fit(epochs=30,
        lr=1e-4,
        validate=True,
        schedule_type="warmup_cosine",
        optimizer_type="adamw")

Selected optimization level O2:  FP16 training with FP32 batchnorm and FP32 master weights.

    Defaults for this optimization level are:
    enabled                : True
    opt_level              : O2
    cast_model_type        : torch.float16
    patch_torch_functions  : False
    keep_batchnorm_fp32    : True
    master_weights         : True
    loss_scale             : dynamic
    Processing user overrides (additional kwargs that are not None)...
    After processing overrides, optimization options are:
    enabled                : True
    opt_level              : O2
    cast_model_type        : torch.float16
    patch_torch_functions  : False
    keep_batchnorm_fp32    : True
    master_weights         : True
    loss_scale             : dynamic
    Warning:  multi_tensor_applier fused unscale kernel is unavailable, possibly because apex was installed without --cuda_ext --cpp_ext. Using Python fallback.  Original ImportError was: ModuleNotFoundError("No module named 'amp_C'")
    
    0.00% [0/30 00:00<00:00]
    0.00% [0/32 00:00<00:00]
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-15-b8d5301e0d4e> in <module>
          3             validate=True,
          4             schedule_type="warmup_cosine",
    ----> 5             optimizer_type="adamw")
    
    ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fast_bert/learner_lm.py in fit(self, epochs, lr, validate, schedule_type, optimizer_type)
        142                 self.model.train()
        143 
    --> 144                 outputs = self.model(inputs, masked_lm_labels=labels)
        145                 loss = outputs[0]  # model outputs are always tuple in pytorch-transformers (see doc)
        146 
    
    ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
        545             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
        546         else:
    --> 547             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
        548         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
        549             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)
    
    ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/data_parallel.py in forward(self, *inputs, **kwargs)
        150             return self.module(*inputs[0], **kwargs[0])
        151         replicas = self.replicate(self.module, self.device_ids[:len(inputs)])
    --> 152         outputs = self.parallel_apply(replicas, inputs, kwargs)
        153         return self.gather(outputs, self.output_device)
        154 
    
    ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/data_parallel.py in parallel_apply(self, replicas, inputs, kwargs)
        160 
        161     def parallel_apply(self, replicas, inputs, kwargs):
    --> 162         return parallel_apply(replicas, inputs, kwargs, self.device_ids[:len(replicas)])
        163 
        164     def gather(self, outputs, output_device):
    
    ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/parallel_apply.py in parallel_apply(modules, inputs, kwargs_tup, devices)
         83         output = results[i]
         84         if isinstance(output, ExceptionWrapper):
    ---> 85             output.reraise()
         86         outputs.append(output)
         87     return outputs
    
    ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/_utils.py in reraise(self)
        367             # (https://bugs.python.org/issue2651), so we work around it.
        368             msg = KeyErrorMessage(msg)
    --> 369         raise self.exc_type(msg)
    
    RuntimeError: Caught RuntimeError in replica 1 on device 1.
    Original Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/parallel_apply.py", line 60, in _worker
        output = module(*input, **kwargs)
      File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 547, in __call__
        result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
      File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apex-0.1-py3.7.egg/apex/amp/_initialize.py", line 197, in new_fwd
        **applier(kwargs, input_caster))
      File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/modeling_roberta.py", line 231, in forward
        inputs_embeds=inputs_embeds,
      File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 547, in __call__
        result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
      File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/modeling_bert.py", line 727, in forward
        input_ids=input_ids, position_ids=position_ids, token_type_ids=token_type_ids, inputs_embeds=inputs_embeds
      File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 547, in __call__
        result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
      File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/modeling_roberta.py", line 66, in forward
        input_ids, token_type_ids=token_type_ids, position_ids=position_ids, inputs_embeds=inputs_embeds
      File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/modeling_bert.py", line 174, in forward
        inputs_embeds = self.word_embeddings(input_ids)
      File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 547, in __call__
        result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
      File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/sparse.py", line 114, in forward
        self.norm_type, self.scale_grad_by_freq, self.sparse)
      File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 1467, in embedding
        return torch.embedding(weight, input, padding_idx, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
    RuntimeError: arguments are located on different GPUs at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1565272271120/work/aten/src/THC/generic/THCTensorIndex.cu:397
```

Answer (score 0):

"apex was installed without --cuda_ext"
Try running this line:

```
%pip install -v --no-cache-dir --global-option="--pyprof" --global-option="--cpp_ext" --global-option="--cuda_ext" ./apex
```

I'm using the same model without problems.